# Is there a way to detect what type of mouse a user is using?

Tags: jquery, mouse, parallax

I am creating a website with a few parallax scrolling elements and they look great when I'm scrolling with my Mac laptop or using a mighty mouse. But as soon as I switch over to a mouse with a scroll wheel, the parallax areas are incredibly jerky and distracting. If possible, I would like to disable the parallax effect for this mouse type.

Any information or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, You can't natively detect the type of mouse that a user is using via `jQuery` (this is because of how the security model of `JavaScript` is implemented - i.e. it is disallowed access to the OS and Filesystem), but you can do so by in a round-about way by detecting the `UserAgent` of the user, and loading specific `jQuery` code for them.

SEE THIS LINK FOR MORE DETAILS:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

And, this link for a list of UserAgents:

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

REFERENCES
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent